# Attach autoscaling group instances directly to load balancer.

Tags: amazon-ec2, terraform

Is there a way to attach instances in an autoscaling group directly to a Application Load Balancer (ALB) target. My ASG works but they are not attached to the ALB Targets when they are initiated.

Comment: Can you share your Terraform code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `aws_autoscaling_group` resource has a `target_group_arns` option:

- https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/autoscaling_group.html

Comment: It turns out I overlooked the `target_group_arns` parameter.